# JSTL/EL: Converting newline characters to <br> tags

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a jsp page in which I am trying to print some DTOs from a list using their `toString()` method.  Currently, my code looks like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.users}" var="user">
    <li><input type="radio" name="users" value="user">
    <c:out value="${user}"/>
    </input></li>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is that `toString()` contains `\n` instead of `<br>` for newlines.  (I even tried to hard-code the `<br>` tags, but they were printed as literals.)  I am sure this would be much easier using scriptlets, but the powers that be don't want to see any Java code in our view.  Has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a multiline toString() is a great idea. Why don't you print out the fields of user by calling them such as:

```
<c:out value="${user.name}"/> <br/>
<c:out value="${user.age}"/> <br/>
```